# Dynamic resources in a RESTful API

Tags: json, api, rest

There are a lot of questions with this title, but having read them I don't think any of them answer my particular question.

I'm designing what I like to call a "RESTful Internet Jukebox".  Basically, it's a RESTful api that can reach out to various internet music services (like youtube) with a search query, download the music, and add it to an MPD playlist.  I've already implemented a prototype and it's working great, but I don't like the design of my API, specifically with regards to playlist management.

As it is now, I have a Playlist endpoint, with "GET" and "PUT" enabled.  Right now, get returns a list of JSON representations of each song ( the filename of the saved song and it's length ).  Put allows you to, if you know the filenames of all the saved music, put a list of these JSON representations and replace the current playlist.

What I would like is to have each song resource be identified by it's position in the current playlist, and be able to GET / PUT / DELETE them individually.  My problem here is that, if I delete resource ID 5 (the 5th song in the playlist), then the 6th song moves up into the 5th position and becomes that resource.  And as the playlist moves, obviously these ID's will move around.  This doesn't sound very restful to me.  I feel like if you delete a resource it shouldn't be filled back in again unless you put something there.  Is this excusable?  Is there a better way to handle playlist management in a more restful way?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Sequence would only be a valid identifier in the way you are using a list above if no items would ever be inserted between or deleted from the list. It would be more feasible to maintain the order as a extra property of each item and come up with another identity mechanism.

I think you probably need to come up with another way to identify the tracks in your playlist, perhaps a `guid` or `uuid` would suffice. Sequence can be an attribute of each of the playlist items in your playlist if you would like to preserve that behavior in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Use a unique identifier for your *songs*. 
If you create a new *song*, (via POST), you assign it a sequential number as the *id*, you will do this serverside.

Create a resource *playlist* which holds a

```
Collection<Song> songs; // in class Playlist
```

of *songs*. These are mapped one-to-many from *playlist* to *song*.

The resource could look like:

```
/playlist/1001/position/10
```

And beyond that you could implement

```
.../playlist/1001/last , /playlist/1001/shuffle ,  ...
```

Position is then used via PUT like:

```
PUT : /playlist/1001/position/10/song/2003
```

And consumed:

```
GET : /playlist/1001/position/10
```

Or even

```
 /playlist/1001/position/next
```

And

```
/playlist/1001/position/reset ...
```

You could call it player and then go for

```
/playlist/1001/player/reset
```

Or put it in the Request Body.

```
PUT: /playlist/1001      
  { "player" : "reset" }

PUT: /playlist/1001
  { "songId" : "3021_MYUIDSCHEMA" }
```

Maybe with this
      "prepend" : "true"

However if you implement a player like this.  Your GET will have "sideeffect" that the player proceeds ... or you do not move the "index" until one makes a

```
PUT: /playlist/1001
{ "skip" : "1", // for next or more
  "set" :: "10" // for direct set }
```

However, using alone

```
/playlist/xyz/positions/...
```

makes perfect sense.

It is anyways no good idea to take the id as a ordinal number.

In a nutshell : You have **2 choices**:

You change the id of the entity when changing position

```
(id: 5 becomes id: 4)
```

after removal of upfront entity.

Or you change the position

```
(positions[4]: 5 /*where it was before*/ positions[4]: {otherSongsId}
```

This would be a definite start from which you then can evolve gradually.